# Use boost::math::normal_distribution<> in Boost version 1.65

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use  `boost::math::normal_distribution<>` as follows:

```
boost::math::normal_distribution<> nomalDistribution(0,1.0);
```

But I have the following error:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be 2)    boost::math::normal_distribution<> nomalDistribution(0,1.0);
```

I have tryed to put double double in arguments but also fails.

I think that in older Boost version this method works.

The template parameters have to be:

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/normal_dist.html | `typedef RealType value_type;` `typedef Policy   policy_type;` `normal_distribution(RealType mean = 0, RealType sd = 1);`

Comment: @rustyx They do different things. The [math distribution models probabilistic properties of statistical distributions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/stat_tut/weg/normal_example/normal_misc.html), whereas `std::normal_distribution` (also [in boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/random/normal_distribution.html)) adapts a PRNG engine to _generate_ numbers that satisfy the distribution